# Writing doc output to pdf

Tags: r, report, reporters

Hello fellow R enthusiasts,

I am wondering whether we can create a pdf version from docx within R (not using other conversion tools). I create a docx report using `ReporteRs` package. I would like to make a copy of that in pdf copy. Is it possible within R, without using any external softwares? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `pdf('your_file_name.pdf')`
    `#do stuff here that prints graphs`
    `dev.off()`

Comment: Why don't you just change your code by a bit and use R-Sweave instead. No need to go from Markdown -> docx -> PDF.

Comment: I am aware of pdf function to print graphs. But I am not sure whether it can print the list used in `Reporters` package and convert it to a multipage pdf document. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: Apparently ReporteRs could generate markdown `mydoc = addMarkdown( mydoc, text = mkd,
        default.par.properties = parProperties(text.align = "justify",
                padding.left = 0) )`, so you could save a Rmd file `write(mydoc, file = "input.Rmd", )`, then use rmarkdown to print a pdf  `render("input.Rmd", "pdf_document")`

Comment: @Robert where does the `write function` comes from? Base? I don't see a  `write` function in `ReporteRs`. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: Yes, it is from Base. Tell us if it works!

Comment: @Robert, no it didn't work. It threw an error.I am not sure whether a list made by `Reporters`  can be converted to Rmd easily like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Disclaimer: This answer came up in google group of `ReporteRs`.

```
writeDoc( doc, file = docfile)
system(paste("libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf  ", docfile), intern = TRUE)
```

It needs libreoffice application to be installed in your system.